# Pandas rolling apply returning NaN in unexpected ways

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where one of my columns contains NaNs and I'm attempting to find the rolling average of the valid numbers in the column. I'm attempting to do this with rolling apply, using a custom function and passing the rolling window raw. Alternatives I've seen are to replace the NaNs with 0, but as I understand it this would artificially deflate my mean (more entries, same sum, smaller average).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mySpecialNumber = 50

def nanMean(arr):
    return arr[~np.isnan(arr)].mean()

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df['rollingAVG'] = df['nanColumn'].rolling(mySpecialNumber).apply(nanMean, raw=True)
```

The above fills `df['rollingAVG']` with NaN values, only NaNs. Whereas I can use:

```
singleAVG = nanMean(df['nanColumn'][0:mySpecialNumber].values)
```

And get a totally reasonable average that accurately reflects the by-hand calculation.

Hope this isn't a duplicate; I couldn't find anything else like it around, so I suspect I must be goofing. I'm also open to alternatives that still produce the results I'm looking for, but this seemed like the most straightforward way I could find.

I'm on macOS 13.4.1, running python 3.11.4, pandas 2.0.3, and numpy 1.25.0.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** As suggested I have previously tried to use

```
df['rollingAVG'] = df['nanColumn'].rolling(mySpecialNumber).mean()
```

as well as

```
df['rollingAVG'] = df['nanColumn'].rolling(mySpecialNumber).apply(np.mean, raw=True)
```

but the problem persists; `df['rollingAVG']` is still full of NaNs.

I can also guarantee the array is full of NaNs; I'm not just looking at the first or last 50 entries, I have set `np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)` and can verify that `df['rollingAVG'].values` is a ~1300 entry array full of NaNs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `np.mean()` ignores NaNs anyway. I just tried `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 4]})` Then `df['a'].mean()` and got 2.5, as expected. So basically just replace your function `nanMean` with a simple `np.mean` in the `apply`.

Comment: Also, If for another reason you do want to filter out NaNs from a series, I think it's best practice in Pandas to use `s[~s.isna()]` rather than `s[~np.isnan(s)]`.

Comment: I'll make the change re:`.isna()` but unfortunately the dataframe mean method yields the same results on the rolling window. That is to say `df['rollingAVG'] = df['nanColumn'].rolling(mySpecialNumber).mean()` just fills `df['rollingAVG']` with NaNs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just now realizing I misread your suggestion. Using `np.mean` in the `apply` method *also* yields `df['rollingAVG']` being filled with only NaNs.

Comment: Are you sure **all** values in `df['rollingAVG']` are NaN? Since you are using a rolling window of 50 elements and not providing `min_periods` to `.rolling()` function, you end up filling the first 49 elements of `df['rollingAVG']` column with NaN. It happens because `min_periods` defaults to window size, which is 50, so you should see the value for `singleAVG` that you computed separately at 50th position of `df['rollingAVG']` column.

Comment: Yes, I've printed the entirety of `df['rollingAVG'].values` after `np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)` and I see a ~1300 entry array full of NaNs.

Comment: Could you please double-check the value at `df['rollingAVG'].values[49]`? It should be equal to `singleAVG`.

Comment: I would try passing `min_periods` to rolling function: `df['rollingAVG'] = df['nanColumn'].rolling(mySpecialNumber, min_periods=1).mean()`

Comment: Setting `min_periods` to `1` does result in accurate values after `mySpecialNumber`, but I'm very confused as to why? I have no problem with the first 50 entries being NaN, but without setting `min_periods` why do *all* entries calculate to NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be providing a value to `min_periods`. Please check pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for this argument in `.rolling()` function:

> min_periods: int, default None    Minimum number of observations in
> window required to have a value;     otherwise, result is `np.nan`.
> For a window that is specified by an offset, min_periods will default
> to 1.    For a window that is specified by an integer, min_periods
> will default to the size of the window.

In your case, `min_periods` defaults to window size, which is the value of `mySpecialNumber`, which results in output NaN if any of your 50 values in the window is NaN. Check this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None, 2, 3]})

In [12]: df.rolling(3)['a'].mean()
Out[12]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

If you pass `min_periods`, you'll start to see outputs:

```
In [13]: df.rolling(3, min_periods=1)['a'].mean()
Out[13]: 
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    2.5
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

I would recommend setting `min_periods` to something that make sense for your dataset, depending on how many values could be missing.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience! I had previously read this documentation, before I even posted, and am still confused by the wording: "Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value; otherwise, result is `np.nan`." I originally took this to mean that the `min_periods` parameter only allowed for values when less than `window` rows were available (ie for rows between `min_periods` and `window`), but I'm now realizing that in addition to this `min_periods` allows the window to contain less than `window` non-NaN values. Is this right? Does rolling automatically prune NaNs?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can think of it as a 2-step process: first the presence of valid values is checked within the window (rolling), and then the window aggregation is performed (apply), discarding NaNs by default. If you are interested, there is some additional [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) you could check about working with missing values.

Comment: Incredibly helpful! Thank you so much!